# Sending WM_HSCROLL to other program

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, scrollbar, powerpoint

Im trying to scroll other program (PowerPoint 2013) by sending WM_HSCROLL, 
and it will work only if I offer the correct LPARAM (not NULL) to SendMessage.

The value of LPARAM is dynamic, it will change if you close and open a new program. 
Now I can only get its value by hooking WM_HSCROLL and clicking scroll bar manually.

```
// This is my code: 
LPARAM lParam = 0x0a616c38;  // Found by hooking WM_HSCROLL
SendMessage(hTarget, WM_HSCROLL, SB_LINERIGHT, lParam);
```

So is it possible to get the correct LPARAM programatically?
Many thanks!

p.s. The scroll bar is not a real window in PowerPoint 2013.
p.s. It returns 1 if I use GetScrollInfo(hTarget, SB_CTL, &scrollinfo), but all values inside scrollinfo are zero.
p.s. [Office Home and Student 2013 Official Site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/home-and-student/)

Comment: For what it's worth, `GetScrollInfo` only works when called on a window that is an actual standard Windows scrollbar (ie has a classname of 'SCROLLBAR') when using SB_CTL, or is a window that is using non-client scrollbars - ie has the `WS_HSCROLL`/`WS_VSCROLL` style bits set when using the SB_HORZ/VERT values, so not too surprising it's not working here.

Comment: Use the accessibility interfaces to drive another application's UI. That's what they're for.

Comment: PowerPoint itself offers a couple methods to scroll the current document window.  Depending on what you're after, that might do the job.

Comment: @RaymondChen You mean MSAA and UIAutomation? I would like to try it, but that is more complex in comparison with SendMessage

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I guess you're talking about MS Office (OLE) Automation. I will give it a try if there is no way to find lParam programatically

Comment: Yes, my suggestion would involve COM automation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call GetLastError?

Comment: Yes! Returning 1 means retrieving some values (success i guess) according to MSDN, and GetLastError returns 0.

Comment: FWIW, GetLastError rarely gives much useful info with SendMessage; it will only tell you if the SendMessage call itself failed (eg the HWND was invalid), but not if the message or parameters didn't make sense for that control. Generally you need to rely on the return value in that case, which is often 0 if the control didn't process the message at all (as it is the default return value), or sometimes -1 for some error (eg. LB_ERR).

Comment: @BrendanMcK sorry Unick, I thought you are asking me to call GetLastError after calling GetScrollInfo. I have checked the return value of SendMessage, it is 0 if failing to scroll, and is 1 if success. Also I called GetLastError after failing to scroll by SendMessage, and as BrendanMcK said, GetLastError always returns 0.

Comment: (FYI @Unick - your input here works better as a comment to the original question than an answer, since you're just asking for more information rather than providing an answer to the problem. But good advice all the same!)

Comment: Maybe you need to send WM_HSCROLL several times if one unit is very small. Or maybe you need to try another params SB_PAGERIGHT, SB_PAGELEFT, SB_RIGHT (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787575(v=vs.85).aspx)    (@BrendanMcK Thank you, but I cannot post comment under question)

Comment: @Unick Now I'm sure SendMessage can works if its parameter lParam has correct value, so I don't think the problem is too small unit.

Answer (score 0):

`GetScrollInfo` will probably not work across process boundaries, so I would say that's why you're not getting valid values back.

The `lParam` value of a `WM_HSCROLL` message is either NULL for the standard window scroll bar, or the handle of the scroll control. The handle of the scroll control will obviously change every time the program is run, so you need to find that out yourself before you can reliably simulate scroll input.

To do this, you can use the `FindWindowEx` function to search the parent window (hTarget in your example) for child windows of class "SCROLLBAR". As you will probably find more than one scrollbar child window you'll need some way to tell them apart - most probably, via the window's GWL_ID value as this will probably not change from run to run.

Comment: GetScrollInfo  *should* actually work across process boundaries; but only *if* you're talking to a genuine USER32/ComCtl32 scrollbar in the first place. (Behind the scenes, I suspect it sends a [SBM_GETSCROLLINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787563(v=vs.85).aspx) message, and since that is less than `WM_USER`, should be marshaled by the user32 - unlike say the ComCtl32 messages which force you to marshal the data yourself.) I don't have PPT 2013 to hand, but 2010 seems to use controls with classname of "NetUI" for its scrollbars...

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Thank you! But what if these scroll bars are not real windows? That means I cannont get their handles by FindWindowEx or Spy++.

Comment: @Nine - you might want to poke around the app with spy++ and see how the scrollbars show up - and see if any of their HWNDs match the lParam you are seeing. They could be real windows, but not be actual SCROLLBAR windows; or they might not be real windows at all. In either case, it would seem that PPT is using WM_HSCROLL in a non-standard manner (in as much as the lParam may not be a standard scroll control), so all bets are off as to how it is using the lParam value.

Comment: @BrendanMcK I have tried PPT 2010, it works fine with the following code: SendMessage(hScrollbarDlg, WM_HSCROLL, SB_LINERIGHT, hNUIScrollbar), I can find hNUIScrollbar by FindWindowEx or Spy++, but failed to do this to PPT 2013

Comment: @BrendanMcK Also I poked every app (including PPT 2013) running on Windows, but still cannot find any window handle matches this lParam. So I think you're right, PPT is using WM_HSCROLL in its own manner. But I still want to know if there may be some way to find this lParam programatically.

Comment: @nine - HWNDs values tend to be smaller than the one you have above, so I'm almost wondering if it's a pointer... if the control is indeed just reusing the WM_HSCROLL for its own purposes, and sending a pointer to some internal thing, then you may be out of luck here...

Comment: @BrendanMcK I didn't notice that. I also got 0x0b018268, 0x0af49bc0, 0x0a68e230, 0x0af2ac90, 0x0a760de0 in other tries. And I found lParam's value for HScroll is always smaller than for VScroll: lParamH + 0xa0 = lParamV